# is there any Java supported Barcode reader device available?

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to read barcode from barcode device using Java. Please guide me.

Comment: You may be helped by this answer to a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097863/usb-barcode-reader-in-qt4/2097915#2097915

Comment: Can you be more specific ?
What kind of barcode device ? Serial, keyboard wedge, USB ?
What are you planning to do with the input ?
What platform are you running on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you need a scanner that does keyboard inout ? a cCOMM (rS232) scanner a USB scanner that doesnt do keybaord input ??

Most barcode reading is done by simpel barcode to keyboard input. This works without any programming in Java as it is your barcodescanner that just send keybaord events to your application. just put focus in a textfield , scan and it works.

The other options is COMM communication

read all about it 
http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/
and here
http://www.jcontrol.org/download/rxtx_en.html

you can connect USB devices to your computer and with the proper device driver read them as if they are COMM devices
This can be better then using USB itself as its far more complex then COMM communication

Answer (score 2):

Well.. Any barcode reader is able to translate the barcode into characters, right? It works just like you type the characters in with your keyboard. I don't think you need a java-based one.