# Is it possible to read a value from a barcode reader using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, barcode

1. Is it possible to read a value from a barcode reader using asp.net?

   2. any sample codes?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198593/how-to-integrate-barcode-scanner-into-an-asp-net-web-application/2198641#2198641

Comment: you may also find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097863/usb-barcode-reader-in-qt4/2097915#2097915

Comment: You might want to make your question more precise about who has the reader: The server or the client. Just to prevent xyz answers about how to talk to the reader from within ASP.NET, because then you can't use it on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

Many barcode readers shoot the code as a keyboard event, so if your application is focused on a textbox the code would be "typed" right in.