# How to integrate barcode scanner into an ASP.NET Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode-scanner

- How to integrate barcode scanner into an ASP.NET Web application?
- Any open source library for doing it?

Comment: Have you found the solution

Answer (score 3):

You (probably) will not have a barcode scanner into your server, but on user computers.

A barcode scanner typically reads a barcode, understand it, and to make that read data to be understood by your computer as entered by keyboard. So you'll just need to send that data to server to be processed.

**EDIT:** I don't have experience on reading barcodes, by you can look into this link to find how to create them: [C# Barcode Generator WebService](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/wsbarcode.aspx). Maybe you should buy one component for both tasks.

Comment: @rubens what barcode library you would suggest for reading and generating barcodes in an asp.net web application...

Answer (score 3):

If you need the barcode written into a textbox, you'll not need extra work to do. Barcode scanners simulate keypress event. Even you can handle window.keypress event to hook the preamble and postamble characters. That way the client do not need to focus on the specific textbox.

Or else the reader uses a hardware driver (? don't know such vendors exists ?) , then you'll need an ActiveX object to wrap the library.