# Scaning document and images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying to Scan document and images in asp.net (C#) program ,please tell me how can i do this in my web application. Is there third party control or any activeX control for this?

Any pointers and suggestion would be much appreciated. 
Thanks !

Comment: duplicate; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198593/how-to-integrate-barcode-scanner-into-an-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [commercial ActiveX control](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx) that you might try. Also [Silverlight 4 COM](http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures) features look pretty promising (look at *Feature #11* in the link).