# Integrating barcode scanner into asp.net application?

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

We have been developing web application in asp.net.
We need barcode scanner to be integrated into our application.
As i know scanner can acts as a key board, can you please tell the method to integrate barcode scanner into this asp.net web based application?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198593/how-to-integrate-barcode-scanner-into-an-asp-net-web-application

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, ling.s Are you guys even *looking* at the questions you're marking as duplicate?! The accepted answer for the first question is just a link to the second one. And **that** one is asking about image recognition, **not** a hardware barcode scanner!

Answer (score 10):

It's just a web page. Make sure the textbox you want the result in has focus right away, and just use the barcode scanner like a keyboard.

You should be able to configure the scanner so it also "presses enter" which will allow your form to be submitted.

This is one piece of hardware they tended to get right - nothing fancy required.