# PHP - Reading data from magnetic card

Tags: php, magnetic-cards

I have to make a application where card reader will be attached to system and I have to read magnetic card reader data.

Magnetic card basically holds user details for registration. So user will give card on reception. receptionist will use card reader and system will read data from card and print the details on a zebra ribbon printer

Is it possible with Php ?

Please share idea how to do this.

Comment: I think you need to do some reading on how web programming works. PHP is server-side, the code never touches the client's browser.  I'm assuming the card reader is on the client's system.

Comment: What do you want PHP to do with reading magnetic card? I think it is a device driver thing.

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19534591/119527), regarding using a barcode scanner in an ASP.NET application. The same logic follows: this is handled at the browser, not the web app.

Answer (score 1):

That is not really possible with PHP. You will need to code this with either C or C++ which is close to PHP language.

The only thing you can do with PHP would be to create an application that the user inputs the credit card number and then you charge them and the user can click on print.

Thats it.